# How to redirect one route from a domain some where else in apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, 301-redirect

I have what, from my searching so far, seems to be a slightly different problem with site redirections than the norm. I need to redirect one particular route from one domain to another on a different port.

So far I've tried a simple 301 Redirect and a rewrite to no avail.

The code looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                      
  ServerName blah.hardsoft.nexus.blah2.blah3.au/phpmyadmin                                                                           
  RewriteEngine on                                                                                                                      
  RedirectMatch "^blah.*nexus.*\/phpmyadmin$" "http://10.1.140.1:8080/phpmyadmin"                                                   
  #RedirectMatch ".*nexus.*" "http://10.1.140.1:8080/phpmyadmin"                                                                         

  #Redirect 301 / http://10.1.140.1:8080/phpmyadmin                                                                                     
  </VirtualHost>                                                                                                                          

<VirtualHost 10.1.140.1:8080>                                                                                                            
  ServerName phpmyadmin                                                                                                                  
  DocumentRoot /var/www-8080                                                                                                             
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see I've tried a couple of redirect matches (one very broad) and a 301 redirect, but in all cases what I end up with is it being redirected to

```
 10.1.140.1/phpmyadmin
```

without the port being appended (at least I think that's whats happening).

Any idea how I should be doing this? Is it even possible?

Comment: "I think that's whats happening" - check the network traffic in the browser dev tools. If you remove your "attempts", does it still redirect? Have you cleared your browser (and any intermediary) caches? What is the URL you are requesting? If you are including the `8080` port in the target URL of your directives and you are not seeing this in the resulting "redirect"(?) then it suggests "something else" is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_rewrite` for redirection with port number. 
First, enable `mod_rewrite` in your server (`a2enmod rewrite`), then add this to your config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/phpmyadmin(.*)$" "http://10.1.140.1:8080/phpmyadmin$1" [L,R=301,NE]
```

I guess the URL to be redirected starts with "/phpadmin", that's why I used the "^" in the regex. If this is wrong, then change the rule accordingly.

Flags used:

[`[L]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) - last rule, no further processing takes place
[`[R=301]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) - Redirect permanent
[`[NE]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) - no encoding of special characters

Then restart your server and test.

**EDIT:** 
Just saw that you had a `RewriteEngine on` in your config, so `mod_rewrite` is probably already enabled. Note that you only need `mod_alias` for a `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch`!